# Hoffman tree Vs, Binary balanced tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given *n* Real Positive numbers *A1,A2....An* build a binary tree **T** such as:

1. Every number is a leaf.
2. Weight of **T** will be minimal as possible. Weight of tree equals to sum of each leaf times its hight.

This question was given to me during a test in Algorithms and Data Structures. My answer in brief was to build a binary tree such that each leaf is A1 to An. Weight of **T** will be sum of *logn**Ai.

I did not get points for this answer. The answer that was awarded full points was to sort the numbers by frequencies and build a Hoffman Tree.

My question is why my answer was ignored?

If A1 to An are all very small numbers, for example ranging from 0 to 1, then the hight of each leaf will become the dominent factor in calculating the weight of the tree.

Help would be apprecieted.

Comment: This question is better asked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as it is an on-topic discussion for that site.  Reference: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  Cheers.

Comment: The second condition is not clear to me, does it mean you multiply leaf depth times the frequency of the number it stores (freq. in original array A), or depth times the number itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original array `A` there may be some elements with many more occurences than the others. You want to construct the tree in a way, that the most frequent elements are higher in the tree than the somewhat rare ones.

Consider the example on this page - ["A quick tutorial on generating a huffman tree"](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/video/mpeg/mpegfaq/huffman_tutorial.html).
The generated huffman tree has weight 228, which is optimal.

The best perfectly balanced tree you could get for the same set has weight 241 (5 and 6 with depth 2, other elements with depth 3), the worst one 294 (switching 5 and 6 with 1 and 2).
Your solution would find something between those, rather than the optimum.

Comment: What if array A is composed of very small numbers? does a hoffman tree still holds?

Comment: I supposed the tree weight is sum of `freq(Ai)*depth(Ai)`, now I see the weight was meant to be the sum of `Ai*depth(Ai)`. So instead of the frequencies, use the numbers themselves to build the huffman tree. Therefore the small numbers get deeper than the big ones, contributing around the same to the overall weight. And to answer your question, small numbers are not a problem, they only lower the weight of the tree. The problem is having big differences in the numbers - which is what the huffman tree solves optimally.